# Flink SQL: Unsupported type(ARRAY<STRING>) to generate hash code

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

I am trying to use flink sql to load avro data and perform various operations. One field of the original data has the Array type, and no matter what operations I want to do, like very simply

```
Table result = inputTable.where(or($("status").isNull(), $("status").isEqual(0)))
```

it always give me errors like

```
org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: 
The main method caused an error: Unsupported type(ARRAY<STRING>) to generate hash code, 
the type(ARRAY<STRING>) is not supported as a GROUP_BY/PARTITION_BY/JOIN_EQUAL/UNION field.
```

Does anyone know how to deal with this issue? Thanks!